# Efficient method to split dataframe multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a `pandas` DataFrame `df` with the size of 168078 rows × 43 columns. A summary of `df` is shown below:

```
              doi                           gender       order       year       ...       count
9384155       10.1103/PRL.102.039801        male         1           2009       ...       1
...
3679211       10.1103/PRD.69.024009         male         2           2004       ...       501
```

The `df` is currently sorted by `count`, and therefore varies from 1 to 501.

I would like to split the `df` into 501 smaller subdata by splitting it by count. In other words, at the end of the process, I would have 501 different sub-`df` with each characteristic `count` value.

Since the number of resulting (desired) DataFrames is quite high, and since it is a quantitative data, I was wondering if:

a) it is possible to split the DataFrame that many times (if yes, then how), and

b) it is possible to name each DataFrame quantitatively without manually assigning a name 501 times; i.e. for example, `df` with `count == 1` would be `df.1` without having to assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice you can do is create a dictionary of data frames. Below I show you an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,6,7,7,5,4,5,6,7],
                 'count':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                 'C':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})
print(df)

   A  count  C
0  4      1  a
1  5      2  b
2  6      3  c
3  7      4  d
4  7      5  e
5  5      6  f
6  4      7  g
7  5      8  h
8  6      9  i
9  7     10  j
```

---

Now we create the dictionary. As you can see the key is the value of count in each row.
keep in mind that here [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) is used to make that in the case where there are two rows with the same count value then they are created in the same dictionary.

```
dfs={key:df[df['count']==key] for key in df['count'].unique()}
```

---

Below I show the content of the entire dictionary created and how to access it:

```
for key in dfs:
    print(f'dfs[{key}]')
    print(dfs[key])
    print('-'*50)


dfs[1]
   A  count  C
0  4      1  a
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[2]
   A  count  C
1  5      2  b
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[3]
   A  count  C
2  6      3  c
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[4]
   A  count  C
3  7      4  d
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[5]
   A  count  C
4  7      5  e
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[6]
   A  count  C
5  5      6  f
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[7]
   A  count  C
6  4      7  g
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[8]
   A  count  C
7  5      8  h
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[9]
   A  count  C
8  6      9  i
--------------------------------------------------
dfs[10]
   A  count  C
9  7     10  j
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use groupby to get the result like below
here
`g.groups`: will give group name (group id) for each group
`g.get_group`: will give you one group with given group name

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice(["a","b","c", "d"], 10),
                 'count':np.random.choice(10,10)
                })

g = df.groupby("count")
for key in g.groups:
    print(g.get_group(key))
    print("\n---------------")
```

**Result**

```
   A  count
3  c      0

---------------
   A  count
9  a      2

---------------
   A  count
0  c      3
2  b      3

---------------
   A  count
1  b      4
5  d      4
6  a      4
7  b      4

---------------
   A  count
8  c      5

---------------
   A  count
4  d      8

---------------
```